# Javascript: Accessing properties on multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, properties

I have an array that loads an array with properties at a certain index:

```
var hotspotLocationsTextAndAudio [];

var myArr = [
[{x:10, y:40, filename:"test",  text:"test"}],
[{x:50, y:60, filename:"test2", text:"test2"}]
];

hotspotLocationsTextAndAudio[window.IDNum] = myArr;
```

To access a property at a certain index of hotspotLocationsTextAndAudio (my case being what window.IDNum equals) at an index of the array inside that (0) and a certain property, I thought I just needed to do the following:

```
alert(hotspotLocationsTextAndAudio[window.IDNum][0].x);
```

That returns undefined.

Comment: Is `hotspotLocationsTextAndAudio[window.IDNum] = arr;` supposed to be `hotspotLocationsTextAndAudio[window.IDNum] = myArr;`?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Just edited. It was being passed through a function before a posted the code, and forgot to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the code you're actually using is this:

```
var hotspotLocationsTextAndAudio [];

var myArr = [
  [{x:10, y:40, filename:"test",  text:"test"}],
  [{x:50, y:60, filename:"test2", text:"test2"]}
];

hotspotLocationsTextAndAudio[window.IDNum] = myArr;
```

The alert code you'll need is:

```
alert(hotspotLocationsTextAndAudio[window.IDNum][0][0].x);
```

The reason being that you wrapped your objects in `[]`, putting them in an array.

Or, in order to have your original alert working, you'll need to change `myArr` to this:

```
var myArr = [
  {x:10, y:40, filename:"test",  text:"test"},
  {x:50, y:60, filename:"test2", text:"test2"}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Ku2tQ/

```
var hotspotLocationsTextAndAudio = [];

var myArr = [
[{x:10, y:40, filename:"test",  text:"test"}],
[{x:50, y:60, filename:"test2", text:"test2"}]
];

alert(myArr[1][0].x);
```

First of all hotspotLocationsTextAndAudio is an empty array, and you never push/merge myArr to it. So trying to access a nested value of an empty array, will fail.

arr, is also never defined.

If possible, keep it simple and try avoiding nested array with too much deep.